# Toggle/hide input group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What is the best way to hide/toggle `the input-group-addon` span in a bootstrap input group? If i just remove it the round corners are cut off from the input
 along with some other display issues such as width

https://jsfiddle.net/45f9nq94/

edit: This is the best I have come up with, ok solution?

https://jsfiddle.net/45f9nq94/1/

edit: Angular example closer to real deal

https://jsfiddle.net/45f9nq94/3/

**Update:**
I rethinked the solution, I think it also looks better for the user https://jsfiddle.net/45f9nq94/7/ Only thing I do not like is that i add to wrap the content of the addon in a new span. Any idea how to change the input-group-addon span with CSS todo the same thing without the extra span?

[image]

Comment: When you remove the `input-group-addon` class, just give it a `border-radius` of... i think 4px.

Comment: Yeh sure, if you're happy with that look etc

Comment: One problem is that width is not same, any good fix for that?

Comment: You could get the width of `input-group` then apply that width to the new text box? Will need to rely on JS/jQuery though me thinks

Comment: I would like to not use js if possible dont like the notion of usign JS for that, see update for better example. I'm using  a inline form and do not want contorl right of input to be affected when hiding addon

Comment: If you remove `div` with `display:inline-block` the label and the input will be  displayed in 2 rows (as the first input); the second input will have the same width of the input-group (`input` + `input-group-addon`). But I'm not sure if it's that you are tring to achieve.

Comment: Im using angular and so do not want to repeat the structure that will create duplicate code for the input (real input is much more advanfed than shown here). Plus bootstrap typeahead behaves strange if you all of sudden replaces it with new one

Comment: One way is to used fixed width for the none inputgrup version ,but feels fragile? https://jsfiddle.net/45f9nq94/5/

Comment: I've seen the Angular edit, so I've tried: `<div ng-class="{'input-group': show}">` and `<span ng-class="{'input-group-addon': show, 'hidden': !show}">`. Unfortunately, I'm still not sure, if that suits your needs

Comment: I rethinked the solution, I think it also looks better for the user https://jsfiddle.net/45f9nq94/7/ Only thing I do not like is that i add to wrap the content of the addon in a new span. Any idea how to change the input-group-addon span with CSS todo the same thing without the extra span?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to remove the `input-group` class as well as hide the `<span>`. As in:

```
 <div ng-class="{'input-group': ...}">
     <input ..../>
     <span ng-if="..." class="input-group-addon"></span>
 </div>
```